# Application.Statusbar not working as expected in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, statusbar

I have an application that uses Application.Statusbar to update the status bar with progress of the macro.  This works fine in Excel 2007 and 2010 but it doesn't display correctly in Excel 2013.

The application executes correctly but the status bar is not updated.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please post a snippet of your code where `Application.Statusbar` can be found and what is the effect you want to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: you need to show your code as were unable to help you without seeing it

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue. Are you sure you are using `DoEvents` after `Application.StatusBar` I tested my code in Excel 2013 and it successfully updates it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Siddharth.  The DoEvents hint was what i needed.  I have never needed it for Excel 2007 or 2010 but something must have changed in 2013 so that I need to yield control.

Have added DoEvents and now works fine.

Comment: Too many nested DoEvents can cause unexpected results. So don't use it in recursive code.