# StatusBar and ScreenUpdate in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I've just gotten into Excel 2013 and am noticing some differences in how macros work (because Microsoft can't leave a good thing alone).

I've always used `Application.ScreenUdpdating = False` at the start of long macros to speed run time. Generally in those instances I've also used `Application.StatusBar = "random text based on macro"` to give myself (or other users) some sense of what's going on and/or how much work is left for the macro to complete.

In 2013, I've learned (from [Application.Statusbar not working as expected in Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278177/application-statusbar-not-working-as-expected-in-excel-2013)) that `DoEvents` is now required. However, when I added in `DoEvents` after my StatusBar updates, it seems to turn screen updating back on, unless a window outside Excel (ex. an open File Explorer window) is given the focus.

Another issue I've noticed is that with DoEvents in the code I can't seem to break the macro manually (i.e. holding ESC doesn't stop the code).

So a few questions:
A) Is DoEvents really required?
B) Is there a way to prevent ScreenUpdates from getting turned back "on" by DoEvents?
C) How do you manually break code running with DoEvents in it?

I can provide the current macro I'm working on if it will help, but since I'm more interested in the general concepts I didn't want to provide specifics for any readers to get bogged down in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I've tried another macro that isn't moving data between two workbooks, and I don't see the screen updating then. However, in this macro, `DoEvents` isn't causing the status bar to update... so I'm pretty lost now

Comment: instead of statusbar, you could use a userform, wich wont be bothered by application.screenupdating (or application.enableevents), and no need of doeevents

Comment: That looks like what I'll have to do.

Comment: DoEvents can cause errors in loops, especially in recursion. I guess whether it is problematic depends on the code you are using it in. I have just faced this problem recently, and would be happy to see a solution so I can keep using the StatusBar for messages.

Comment: @robotik I ultimately just created a tiny user form that is just a text field and a button. I post status information to the text field and the button serves to close the form when the macro finishes. As I've used 2013 more, it seems like StatusBar will serve for smaller macros that don't need to update much and don't handle much data, but just isn't up to the job for bigger programs anymore.

Comment: it is a pity, as i use statusbar for progress feedback in a macro that browses through directories. it is not as intrusive as a text field, it seems more professional, and it's long enough to show file paths. it worked perfectly in the previous version, but now I guess we have to settle for this workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem today so I thought I would share what I found while debugging the issue:

For me I noticed that the status bar was reverting to a previous status bar method while my macro was running. I found that the old message was the last status bar message printed before I disable screen updating. However, new status bar messages were printing temporarily so screen updating wasn't preventing new messages from displaying. I traced the issue to a spot in the macro where I run an executable using:

```
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
errorCode = wsh.Run(exeCMD, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

It appears that calling the executable disrupted the status bar display and excel reverted to displaying whatever status bar message was showing before screen updating was disabled. To solve this I reactivated screen updating before running the executable and then disabled screen updating once the executable was run:

```
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
errorCode = wsh.Run(exeCMD, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Hope this helps someone out there.